# Normalize the dataset that comes without column name

Tags: r, normalization

Working with breast-cancer-wisconsin dataset.

[image]

This data comes without column name and column 2 is the response. i have to normalize column 3-32. How to solve this? any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Considering the nature of the data, I would suggest you to use specialised libraries, such as `DESeq2` or `edgeR`, for this task. For example, assuming `RNA counts`, I would split your table between metadata (`df[,1:2]`) and counts `df[,3:ncol(df)]` and get the normalised counts using `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix()` first and `DESeq()` then. Check the package vignette for the exact commands.

Answer (score 0):

Given data frame `df` as your input data structure, you can use `scale()` to normalize your columns, i.e.,

```
df[3:ncol(df)] <- scale(df[3:ncol(df)])
```

Comment: not working. displayed error since my predictor is 2nd Column.

Comment: @DaOrestes `dput()` your data